# python : update same dictionary keys at different index in a list

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to update same dictionary keys at different index in a list using a for loop.
I am not sure if this is even an allowed format/way to do that with python code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
rc_description_final=["Apple","Orange", "Pineapple"]
rc_action_final = ["Red", "Fruit", "Yellow"]
k=0
while k < len(IDs):
    temp={}
    rc = {}
    temp['Rate'] = [rc]
    d = 0
    print(rc_description_final)
    print(len(rc_description_final))
    while d < len(rc_description_final):

        temp['Rate'][d]['Description'] = rc_description_final[d]

        temp['Rate'][d]['Action'] = rc_action_final[d]

        temp['Rate'].append(rc)

        d = d + 1
    json.dumps(temp)
    print(json.dumps(temp))
    k = k + 1
```

I expect the output as:

```
{
    "Rate Limits": [
      {
        "Description": "Apple",
        "Action": "Red"
      },
      {
        "Description": "Orange",
        "Action": "Fruit"
      },
      {
        "Description": "Pinapple",
        "Action": "Yellow"
      }
    ]
}
```

But I am getting the output as:

```
{
    "Rate Limits": [
    {
        "Description": "Pinapple",
        "Action": "Yellow"
     },
    {
        "Description": "Pinapple",
        "Action": "Yellow"
     },
    {
        "Description": "Pinapple",
        "Action": "Yellow"
     }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I found the issue at the "temp['Rate'] = [rc]". So when the temp['Rate'] change then the rc value will automatically change. which leads you to this output.

Here is my code for your references:

```
import json

rc_description_final=["Apple","Orange", "Pineapple"]
rc_action_final = ["Red", "Fruit", "Yellow"]
k=0
while k < 1:
  temp={}
  temp['Rate'] = []
  d = 0
  print(rc_description_final)
  print(len(rc_description_final))
  while d < len(rc_description_final):
    description_dict = {}

    description_dict['Description'] = rc_description_final[d]
    description_dict['Action'] = rc_action_final[d]

    temp['Rate'].append(description_dict)

    d = d + 1
json.dumps(temp)
print(json.dumps(temp))
k = k + 1
```